# Why does std::atomic_compare_exchange update the expected value?

Tags: c++, multithreading, cpu-architecture, atomic, compare-and-swap

Why does `std::atomic_compare_exchange` and all its brothers and sisters update the passed expected value?

I am wondering if the are any reasons besides the given simplicity in loops, e.g.: is there an intrinsic function which can do that in one operation to improve performance?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The processor has to load the current value, in order to do the "compare" part of the operation.  When the comparison fails the caller needs to know the new value, to retry the compare-exchange (you almost always use it in a loop), so if it wasn't returned (e.g. by modifying the expected value that is passed by reference) then the caller would need to do another atomic load to get the new value. That's wasteful, because the processor has already loaded the value.  You should only be messing about with low-level atomic operations when extreme performance is the only option, so in that case you do not want to perform two operations when one will do.

Comment: *"When the comparison fails the caller needs to know the new value, to retry the compare-exchange"* Personally, I'm actually more often not interested in the actual value - just whether it has a certain value (e.g. nullptr) or not and it is quite annoying that you can't just specify that value as a constant parameter and instead have to create and/or reset a local variable in each iteration. Not saying that is the more common usecase in general, but it would have been nice to have an additional version that doesn't require this.

Comment: @MikeMB, why would you have to do anything on each iteration? Just create a local variable before the loop, pass its address, and you're done, surely? Anyway it seems trivial to create a wrapper that takes the value and uses its address:  `template<class T> inline bool atomic_compare_exchange_strong(std::atomic<T>* obj, T expected, T desired) { return std::atomic_compare_exchange_strong(obj, &expected, desired); }`

Comment: @JonathanWakely: E.g. if you search for a free slot in an array and want to reserve it atomically: If you fail to reserve one slot because someone else was faster you don't need to know the new value. You go on to the next slot and again set the expected value to *"empty"*.

Comment: *"It seems trivial to create a wrapper that ..."* by that reasoning a lot of types, and functions in the standard library wouldn't be necessary ;) - doesn't mean I'm not happy that they are there. But obviously that particular wrapper wasn't important enough for anyone to write a paper and fight it through the standardization process.

Comment: @MikeMB Thanks for explaining the use case, that makes sense. A good rule of thumb for additions to the standard library is that they should either be things that are hard for users to get right, or simple things that everybody reimplements over and over again. This wrapper is not hard to get right, and as you said is not the common use case so not widely needed. Obviously not everything in the std::lib meets one of those criteria :)

Comment: @JonathanWakely Like everybody's favorite `std::exchange()`? :-)

Comment: Sorry to dig out this old post, but I just had another example where the automatic update is really annoying: When you implement an adaptive lock, where you need more than one bit of information (and hence std::atomic_flag is not enough) but the value you wait for remains 0.

Answer (score 2):

> is there an intrinsic function which can do that in one operation to improve performance

That can do what, specifically?  The instruction has to load the current value to do the comparison, so on a mismatch yielding the current value costs nothing and is pretty much guaranteed to be useful.

Answer (score 2):

> I am wondering if the are any reasons besides the given simplicity in loops, e.g.: is there an intrinsic function which can do that in one operation to improve performance?

Yes. For example on x86 this compare-and-swap (CAS) operation will be implemented by [cmpxchg](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmpxchg) and this operation updates the expected value (passed in `rax`) when the CAS fails. Arm CAS looks to be the same (though I couldn't actually tell from the documentation, assembly examination was required).

The outcome can be seen [in goldbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/7vqqGqPr4), where returning the updated expected value after a CAS requires no second read: we may just return the register value which has been already been loaded with the actual read value.

That C++ defines the operation in this way pretty much means the underlying hardware CAS (if CAS is used) must behave this way for efficient operation. If you had a CAS which returned a failure indication but not the value, you can't simply emulate the atomic behavior by a subsequent read: it wouldn't be atomic and could even return the "desired" value which is an impossible result. So I think you'd need a CAS loop to implement CAS!

See an answer and discussion in comments on [a Java 8 Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73349502/java-8-impl-on-compare-and-exchange-not-compare-and-set) about implementing `compareAndExchange` on top of the older `compareAndSet` that only returns a `bool` status, not the updated value.  For some use-cases (but maybe not all), a stale old value on failure could be indistinguishable from spurious failure for `compare_exchange_weak`, but maybe not generally equivalent enough for a compiler to skip looping even for `compare_exchange_weak` on a hypothetical ISA that didn't leave the load result in a register.  And definitely not for `compare_exchange_strong`.

Also related: GNU C legacy [`__sync` builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fsync-Builtins.html) had both `__sync_bool_compare_and_swap` and `__sync_val_compare_and_swap`.  So you could get one or the other of the old value or the `bool` status as a return value, with args taken by value.  Using `__sync_val_compare_and_swap`, you check for success with `retval == expected` (since it's not a "weak" CAS; neither is the `bool` version).  You can't get the value from just the `bool`, but you can get the `bool` from the value (and hopefully compilers would optimize that into using the FLAGS output of `lock cmpxchg` on x86 instead of an extra `cmp` on the potentially-updated integer register).

Comment: If the updated value of `expected` isn't used, compilers could optimize away the loop on a hypothetical ISA that didn't make the load result available on failure.  Like how x86 compilers can optimize `fetch_or` into x86 `lock or` instead of a CAS retry loop if the return value is unused.  https://godbolt.org/z/9GzvM35E6 (GCC and Clang even manage `lock bts` for single-bit masks where only that bit in the return value is checked.)

Comment: @PeterCordes you mean in the case of that ISA needing to emulate C++ CAS? Yes they could, but I think the main problem is when expected is used but the specific semantics C++ gives it (that it must plausibly be the value from the failed CAS) are not necessarily. I don't think the compiler can detect that in most cases, so you end up the loop though maybe it could combine the inner and outer loops in the case the C++ level function was itself used in a loop?

Comment: Yeah, that's the situation I was talking about.  And yeah, agreed.  Doesn't feel worth the effort to try to prove anything rigorous because real hardware doesn't work that way.