# Java 8 impl on Compare And Exchange (Not Compare and Set!)

Tags: java, java-8, atomic, compare-and-swap, atomicreference

In java 17, `AtomicReference` has the `compareAndExchange` method which is like `compareAndSet`, but instead of returning a boolean, it returns the value right before the atomic action. I need that to implement a custom concurrent structure.

Due to limitations on the project, I have to use only Java 8 features. Some digging revealed `VarHandle` which has `compareAndExchange`. However, `VarHandle` requires Java 9.

Therefore, it seems that I have to implement the `compareAndExchange` myself. But how to do so efficiently with the existing methods? (And what about the `compareAndExchangeWeak` version?)

(I cannot rely on any third-party libraries, BTW)

Comment: Why are you restricted to Java 8? Given Java 17 is the current LTS, you or your company should really consider upgrading.

Comment: It's because of... Well. Game modding. (Or, Minecraft modding more precisely.) Supporting many versions of MC, even very old but popular one, is important still.

Comment: `for(;;) { V current = ref.get(); if(current != expected || ref.compareAndSet(current, newValue)) return current; }`

Answer (score 5):

This is close but has an observable difference in at least one case:

```
V witness = ref.get();
if (ref.compareAndSet(oldValue, newValue)) {
    return oldValue;
} else {
    return witness;
}
```

If `witness != oldValue`, the `witness` value is not necessarily the correct value of the reference *at the instant we do the compare-and-set*.

However, it is not clear whether that value would be useful anyway ... so "close but not exactly right" may be sufficient.  With a 100% correct `compareAndExchange`, the returned `witness` doesn't tell the caller what the state of the reference is *now*.  Another thread could have changed the reference by the time that caller tries to use the returned value.

For example, this could return a value that matches `oldValue` without having done the store.  e.g. if multiple threads run this simultaneously with the same `oldValue` when `ref` has that value, they can all loads `witness = oldValue`, but only one will succeed the CAS.  So you can't safely use the return value to determine whether your CAS "won the race" to update `ref`.  You need to keep to `bool` return value from `compareAndSet` for that.

I don't think it is possible to do an exact emulation of `compareAndExchange` without using locks ... which would largely defeat the purpose of using an `AtomicReference`.

Comment: I don't think this has the correct effects, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I **know** it doesn't have the correct effect.  That's the point.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: But is there ever a case where we can distinguish this from a failed CAS?  Java doesn't allow memory ordering weaker than sequential consistency, so I think this is indistinguishable from `ref.get()` being the load part of a failed CAS.  Whether a thread has done one vs. two loads isn't a directly-observable side effect.

Comment: I think this works, and would only be really worried about it if there was any code between `ref.get()` and the CAS attempt, and/or weaker memory orders were possible.  Although a failed CAS is potentially just a pure load, not an RMW, on some machines, so maybe even weaker memory orders would be fine for a hypothetical C++ version of this, as long as `.get()` and the CAS use the same memory order strength for the failure side, and the success load side.

Comment: @PeterCordes - It could be "observable sometimes" rather than "guaranteed observable".  But my thought is that it is hard to see how it matters that you return the wrong witness following a failed CAS.  It would be indistinguishable from another thread updating the reference immediately afterwards.

Comment: (ISO C++11 compare_exchange_weak has always updated `oldValue` by reference, like the GNU C `__atomic`, as well as returning a bool for success/fail.  The old GNU C [`__sync_bool_compare_and_swap`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fsync-Builtins.html) existed, but so did `__sync_val_compare_and_swap` that just returned the old value, not the compare success.  So you could manually compare after to also see if the compare succeeded, without needing to emulate this way.  And didn't take a memory-order parameter.  So my C++ hypothetical is just hypothetical.)

Comment: I wonder if a loop with get witness, compare witness with expected, return witness if unequal, otherwise compare-and-set, return witness if true end loop would be better, or if that just makes it perform badly with the same end result.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - Tried that thought.  The problem is you get into an infinite loop.  (If you don't care about `oldValue`, you can replace this with `getAndUpdate(() -> newValue())` ... but the semantics are different to `compareAndExchange`.)

Comment: I think I'm not familiar enough with Java memory-model terminology.  Does "observable sometimes" just mean you were racing with another store and might or might not have seen it?  I think this emulation is still equivalent (except perhaps performance) to a single CAS attempt at either the moment the `get.ref()` takes a value (on later CAS failure), or at the moment the CAS itself executes (on success).  Since those two operations are back to back in one thread, I don't think it can ever matter which of the two loads (separate or part of CAS) was the one that counted.  (@MarkRotteveel).

Comment: By "observable sometimes" I meant ... "not guaranteed by *happens before* relationships, so behavior depends on ... things".

Comment: Ok yeah, that's what I was already assuming, that it was racing with other writers, otherwise it would be trivially correct.  I could certainly be missing something, but my intuition says this is fine.  Yes, you could see a `witness` that matched `oldValue` and then have the CAS fail, but in that case it's as if the earlier load never happened.  Except **this could potentially return `oldValue` *without* having done a store of `newValue`**.  So there we go, that's a potentially observable difference.

Comment: Yup.  I think it is potentially observable too, hence my "close ... but not exactly right" characterization of the "solution".

Comment: Is there any possible noticable difference regarding ABA problem? I currently cannot think of any but I'm worried that I'm missing something there.

Comment: Potentially, yes.   But please update the question to provide a concrete example where you would be using (real) `compareAndExchange` to address an ABA problem.  Then we can be sure we know what you mean.

Comment: @李浩穎 : I just edited this answer to explain in more detail the one case I've thought of where the observable results would be different.  There may be other cases, too.  However, even `compareAndExchange` doesn't avoid ABA problems in general, but I don't *think* this emulation would make ABA problems worse.  If you're using a 2-element struct with a counter avoid ABA problems, or using some bits of a wider integer as a sequence counter for the same reason, this doesn't break that.

Comment: Thanks. And I guess it now functions like `CompareAndExchangeWeak` if I also pass in a mutable boolean. And I think with a slight modification, (by retrying if weak fails yet return value is the same as the expected value), it could be a full (and a bit slow) `compareAndExchange`?

Comment: @李浩穎: `compareAndSet` doesn't fail *spuriously*.  If it fails, there definitely was a value other than `oldValue` in `ref` at the time it executed.  You just don't know what it is.  Some algorithm might want to retry until success or `witness != oldValue`, but most use-cases don't need that.  It would be a bad idea to introduce retries where not necessary, amplifying contention in cases where it already exists.

Comment: Though that does still mean if I need exact (or as best as it could in a *as if* way) c++'s `compareAndExchange`, I would still need the retires right? And there isn't any other better methods right?

Comment: And in your case where the CAS fails, and yet the witness value is the same as expected, then by the 'as if' rule, I could say that the value was changed before the operation, and said `CompareAndExchangeWeak` operation just fail spuriously. Is this still correct?

Comment: Wait... I flipped that around. I meant as if the value was changed after the operation, which said operation just fails spuriously.

Comment: @李浩穎 : Were you still replying to me?  You didn't @ notify me but I just randomly happened to look at this thread again.  Yeah, treating it as a `compare_exchange_weak` that could spuriously fail would be one way to account for the possibility of `witness == oldValue` but still failure.  That is possible with a C++ CAS_weak

Comment: @PeterCordes - my feeling while writing the answer you recently cross-linked to this one is that you could emulate it correctly using this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73349502/java-8-impl-on-compare-and-exchange-not-compare-and-set#comment129535218_73349594.